# How to clear the TextFormField externally in an Autocomplete widget?

Tags: flutter

As you know, it is a basic requirement that; after the user makes an entry in an Autocomplete field (either by entering a new value or selecting an existing value from the dropdown list) and then press a 'Submit' button or 'Delete' button (say, to update the database); the old entry in the  TextFormField should be cleared automatically for the next entry.

How can this be programmatically done in a simple way  (for example, like Autocomplete.TextFormField.clear )   in Flutter?

I have tried several ways, but am unable to access/ modify the TextEditingController from an outside function.

Thank you in advance for any advice, please!

Comment: check [fieldViewBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete/fieldViewBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this for the benefit of whoever who reads this post, having a similar requirement.

A solution lies with flutter_typeahead widget, found here:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

It could be used instead of RawAutocomplete or Autocomplete widgets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`RawAutocomplete`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawAutocomplete-class.html) to access the text editing controller from outside the Autocomplete. The RawAutocomplete is similar to Autocomplete, but it also provides the `textEditingController` and `focusNode` properties.

Note that if you pass in a `textEditingController`, you must also provide a non-null `focusNode` and `fieldViewBuilder`.

An example of modifying the textEditingController from outside the Autocomplete can be seen below.

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
final _focusNode = FocusNode();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawAutocomplete<String>(
        textEditingController: _controller,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        fieldViewBuilder: (context, textEditingController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) =>
                  TextFormField(controller: _controller),
...
)};

//Then in your outside function
setState(() {
    _controller.clear();
};
```